# MS excel-drop down list-2016

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am having drop down list of 5 items suppose `A,B,C,D,E`. I want to restrict A should be chosen not more than 5 times & in same column B will be chosen 12 times from same drop down list & C will be 3 times in same column from same drop down list & same for D and E will be chosen 6 & 7 times in same column & same drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will limit the user's choices as they fill out the dropdown list.  It uses a combination of `Named Ranges`, `Data Validation`, `IF` statements, and `COUNTIF` statements to determine which choices are available.

A helper cell with the following formula should be placed on your sheet and referenced by Data Validation via the `INDIRECT` function (the formula assumes your dropdown list is in the `range H2:H21`):

```
=IF(COUNTIF($H$2:$H$21,"C")<3,"ABCDE",IF(COUNTIF($H$2:$H$21,"A")<5,"ABDE",IF(COUNTIF($H$2:$H$21,"D")<6,"BDE",IF(COUNTIF($H$2:$H$21,"E")<7,"BE",IF(COUNTIF(H2:H21,"B")<12,"B","N/A")))))
```

First, create a table much like the following to allow `Named Ranges` to be assigned.  This table contains all of your criteria and possible choices:

[image: range]

Assign named ranges for each dropdown list scenario:

[image: range2]

Use `INDIRECT` in the `Data Validation` list reference:

[image: image2]

Comment: Hi @Ashwin, let me know if this solution worked for you.  If so, mark it as the answer.